# Choosing Metro Apps as UI technology for products

Tags: user-interface, windows-8, microsoft-metro, product

We are in the process of choosing UI technology for our line of products targeted to Microsoft platforms and designed to serve retail industry (or custom built apps). The reason I am inclined towards Metro Apps (out of Windows Forms, WPF, and Metro Apps) is the rich UI it provides, however, there are questions around its viability:

1. What is the future of Metro Apps? Are they going to stay? How long?
2. Do these Metro Apps are suitable for line of products mentioned (or
   enterprise in general)?
3. Where do existing technologies (Windows Forms and WPF) stand in the presence of Metro Apps?
4. What does the learning curve look like?

I am seeking insight and opinion from beloved community to help answer the questions.

Thank you.

Comment: 1.) ask this MS. 2.) no, too limited API and apps run sandboxed. Also the distribution only over the store sucks. For Enterprise users can can sideload them. but this requires Enteprise edition of windows or sideload keys 3.) more possibilities and much more components compared to WinRT 4.) for WPF devs not that high, XAML is the base of WinRT